# How does xsd report errors

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm using an XSD with Visual Studio, however the results are not as expected.

I've got a unique constraint on one element. When I deliberately break the Xml by introducing a duplicate, intellisense highlights the error, however when it then lets me compile and run the code, nothing further happens and the error is allowed to cascade through.

Is is possible i've missed there anything or am doing something wrong, or is this it as far as error validation is concerened in XSD's?

```
    public static T CreateClassFromXml<T>(string path, string root, XmlReaderSettings settings)
        where T : class
    {
        path.ThrowNullOrEmpty("path");
        settings.ThrowNull("settings");

        File.Exists(path).ThrowFalse(string.Format("'{0}' could not be found", path));

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), new XmlRootAttribute() { ElementName = root });

        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(path, settings))
        {
            return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
```

Calling code:

```
        var xsd = context.Server.MapPath(Paths.Xml + "Wikis.xsd");
        File.Exists(xsd).ThrowFalse(string.Format("'{0}' could not be found", xsd));

        var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.Schemas.Add(null, xsd);
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;

        var xml = context.Server.MapPath(Paths.Xml + "Wikis.xml");
        var metaList = XmlHelper.CreateClassFromXml<List<WikiMeta>>(xml, "AllMeta", settings);
```

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what do you expect Visual Studio to do with your XML file. You would need to post more details, starting with the version of VS, and then going down the properties you see when clicking on your XML file as part of a project; for e.g., what is the Build Action? Did you set a Custom Tool? What is that Custom Tool? If you simply want to ensure that XML files are valid as posted in your project, then you either rely on a custom tool that does validation, or you could use a build event, etc.

This is an example you could use to build your custom validation in the build process. Set your tool path and pass parameters through some mechanism... The parameters could be the actual file you wish to validate, or it could contain a list of file locations and associated XSD locations... Any exit code other than zero would be considered an error (so your build could stop). Add this XML as part of your project file, or use appropriate UI in the project Properties editor.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Tool Condition="'$(Tool)' == ''">"full path to your exe"</Tool>
    <ToolParams>"$(ProjectDir)$(TargetName).xml"</ToolParams>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="AfterCompile">
    <Exec Condition=" '$(RunTool)' == 'true' " Command="$(Tool) /parms:$(ToolParms)"/>
</Target>
```

Comment: I'm using VS 2010 pro. Not got much experience working with build events etc, so I don't know where to start. I have managed to get a result (runtime error) using updated code.

Comment: Do you embedded these files as resources and use them at runtime? or do you copy them as output?